# How to format number with "." as thousands separator and "," as decimal separator?

Tags: mysql, sql

How to format a number with "." as thousands separator and "," as decimal separator in MySQL?

I'm using the `Format()` function like:

```sql
SELECT Format(myNumber, 2) AS myNumberFormatted 
FROM ...
```

But it returns a number like:

```
1,000,000.00
```

Instead, I want:

```
1.000.000,00
```

How to do this in MySQL ?

Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

MySQL>=5.5:

```
SELECT FORMAT(10000000.5, 2, 'de_DE') AS format
```

MySQL<5.5:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(FORMAT(10000000.5,2), ',', ':'), '.', ','), ':', '.') AS format
```

Comment: I'm using MariaDB 5.5.50 and using the locale 'de_DE' it works as expected. However, for the locales 'nl_NL' and 'nl_BE' the thousands seperator is completely missing. This is probably a bug. For number formatting I have to pretent Dutch speaking visitors are German (I won't tell them).

Comment: Greetings from 2021. Same problem persists. Also with `fr-FR`.

Comment: Well, for 7+ years that the answer was here - it never claimed to be working for MariaDB..

Answer (score 8):

specify locale.

```
FORMAT(myNumber, 2, 'de_DE')
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16b6a/1)

Comment: requires MySQL 5.5+ but the best solution