# MySQL: thousands separator with count(*)

Tags: mysql, number-formatting

I have an MySQL-statement like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM xy
```

I get a number like 1443223. But I want thousands-separators, e.g. 1.443.223. What I found here (use of FORMAT) produced only an error. I tried e.g.

```
SELECT FORMAT(COUNT( * ), 2, 'de_DE')
```

Well ... Perhaps anybody out there is knowing an answer? Thanks!

EDIT:
The error I am getting is

> Error Number: 1582
>
> Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'FORMAT'
>
> SELECT FORMAT(COUNT( * ), 2, 'de_DE') AS anzahl FROM xy
>   a WHERE a.typ = 'IHK' AND a.datum >=2014

Comment: Please mention here what you get error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19376297/how-to-format-number-with-as-thousand-separator-and-as-decimal-separato

Comment: I added the error to my post. @RonakShah I know this answer but I was not able to transfer it to my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried these two queries and they are perfectly working fine:

```
SELECT FORMAT((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM xy), 2, 'de_DE');
SELECT FORMAT((SELECT count(*) FROM xy a WHERE a.typ = 'IHK' AND a.datum >=2014), 2, 'de_DE') AS anzahl;
```

the second query is from the error that you are getting, try this once, it should work. I tested it.

What is the version of MySQL that you are using? try this also:

```
SELECT FORMAT((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM xy), 2);
SELECT FORMAT((SELECT count(*) FROM xy a WHERE a.typ = 'IHK' AND a.datum >=2014), 2) AS anzahl;
```

Comment: in first 2 SQLs, there are 3 arguments to the method FORMAT while in 2nd example there are 2 arguments and that is the error that you are getting

Comment: I have MySQL 5.1.73. Your first 2 suggestions produce errors, the second two work but produce output like 158,470.00.

Comment: If I use your second ones and write ..., 0 (instead of ,2) I get the number without decimals (that's what I want). Do you have an idea how to get rid of the commata and use points instead?

Comment: yeah, you can alway remove it by using:

select substring_index((SELECT FORMAT((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM xy), 2)), '.', 1) AS anzahl;  

Try it and tell if it works for you.

Comment: perhaps i got your question wrong, try this:    

SELECT REPLACE((select substring_index((SELECT FORMAT((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM xy), 2)), '.', 1)), ',', '.') as anzahl;

Comment: thanks, yes, this does work! my problem is that I am running a big site, I cannot use four-fold-nested subselects due to performance issues, or what do you think? I have to look for another solution obviously.

Comment: you can get the count in a variable and then can run the util methods (replace, substring_index) on that. I ran this query on a table with 1.57 Million records and got the result in 0.234 seconds. The utility methods won't be a performance overhead. Still, if you are asking for a different solution, then you should get the value in whatever server side (java/php/ruby) you are using and do the conversion there.

Comment: That sounds great; what do you mean with "get the count in a variable"?

Comment: I meant get the required result in a variable let's call it val, and then run util methods on the variable;     
set @val = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fact_event);    
SELECT REPLACE( (select substring_index( (SELECT FORMAT(@val, 2)), '.', 1)), ',', '.') as anzahl;

Comment: thekosmix, thank you very much. ONE (:-) last question: do you think this will be faster than using php for number-format?

Comment: I think it will be better to experiment and see by yourself, but if it's upto me, i would do that in php. and one last thing if you think my solution helped you then can you accept and upvote it so that others, looking for same thing, will be benefitted by it.

Comment: I wanted to do this anyway, because it is solved now. Astoninglishly there seems to be no "easy" solution in MySQL. Thanks a lot for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this:

```
SELECT FORMAT((SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM XY), 2, 'de_DE')
```

Comment: you use the same query which I wrote above?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it like so:

```
SELECT FORMAT(COUNT(*), 2, 'de_DE') FROM your_table
```

and it works.
Maybe you were missing the FROM... clause?

Comment: No, I did not forget the FROM-clause. I get the same error.