# format number after count it first in mysql

Tags: count, format, mysql-workbench

I need to format the resulted number after count it first

```
select
count(`mybooks.IDbook') as book
from mybooks
```

the query returns e.g. 3456
and I need to format is as 3.456
thank's

Comment: try this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_format

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format number with "." as thousand separator, and "," as decimal separator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19376297/how-to-format-number-with-as-thousand-separator-and-as-decimal-separato)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query will show your book count with decimal points as separators:

```
SELECT REPLACE(FORMAT(COUNT(0), 0), ',', '.') AS book
FROM mybooks
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/058786/7)

Comment: I added a demo for anyone else who has a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

solved as
        SELECT 
        REPLACE(FORMAT(COUNT(0), 0), ',', '.') AS `books`
    FROM
        `mybooks`
thank's for your time